# How to update ModelStateError after file download?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel, modelstate

[**Web dev noob** - is not familiar with the terms javascript, jquery, ajax and similar terms, and cannot quite comprehend its concepts, and therefore most "basic" solutions presented in SO. Came from Winforms development]

**What I'm trying to do**:

1. Upload an excel file (multiple rows) that was encoded based on a template (there is an `input type="file"`, and an Upload button)
2. Perform all kinds of validation (e.g. no file was selected, a file other than xls/xlsx is selected, the actual parsing and validation of the uploaded file, etc) - which is done using **`ModelState.AddModelError()`**
3. If on parsing the file, there were errors found by the validation logic, the excel file that was uploaded is modified, and a new column "Errors" is added to it, which contains the errors found per row, and is downloaded as some log file (still an excel file), where I used `EPPlus`.
4. If no errors, just display a message informing the user that the upload was a success.

**My problem**:

So far I can already upload a file, and then validate if success or with errors. If the latter, I can already download the error log file. What I can't do is try to **combine actions** that produces a validation error, and then followed by intentionally uploading an excel file *that* has errors. Please refer below for the actual steps to be taken.

Step 1: For example, the user clicked the "Upload" button without first browsing for the relevant file, the message for example "Error: No file was selected" is displayed.

Step 2: The user now selects a file after performing step 1, but this file has errors that won't pass the validation logic.

```
private void CreateErrorLog(Stream stream, string fileName)
{
    this.ModelState.AddModelError("BulkUploadError", "Please refer to the downloaded file for errors.");
    // generation of the excel log file
    ...
    this.DownloadExcel(excelPackage, Path.GetFileName(newFileName));
}

public void DownloadExcel(ExcelPackage package, string fileName)
{
    this.Response.Clear();
    this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    this.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename={fileName}");
    this.Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
    this.Response.End();
}
```

Now as I expect it, this code should replace the ModelState error that was shown in step 1: "Error: No file was selected" → "Please refer to the downloaded file for errors."

**The actual scenario**:

The log file *is* downloaded, but the error message is **not** updated.

**What I tried to do** (considering my zero knowledge in web dev):

Tried some random debugging - I commented out the line wherein `DownloadExcel` method is called, and with this, the error message **successfully updates**.

**What I can formulate from this**:

Is that the download definitely blocks the updating of the ModelState error message that is displayed.

**Requirement**:

1. Definitely need to download the error log file
2. Also definitely need the error message to match the actual scenario

**How can I now do both?**

Also, my View is something like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bulk Upload";
}

<h2>Bulk Upload</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Bulk", "MyModel", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.ValidationMessage("BulkUploadError", new { @class = "text-danger" })<br>
    <label for="file">File path:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xls, .xlsx" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn main-button" />
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```